# Showing the first tr by default using table grouping in angular js

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to show the first `tr` in the table and hiding other `tr` by default. I tried to use ng-show and ng-hide but it is not working.

This is not my plunker, I used it to get the grouping and I'm trying the above in the same. So, by default area1 should be visible and area2 should be collapsed.Only on clicking area2, area1 should collapse.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope, $timeout, NgTableParams) {

  $scope.data = [{
      uid: 'User 11',
      name: 'Name 11',
      area: 'Area 1'
    },
    {
      uid: 'User 12',
      name: 'Name 12',
      area: 'Area 1'
    },
    {
      uid: 'User 21',
      name: 'Name 21',
      area: 'Area 2'
    },
    {
      uid: 'User 22',
      name: 'Name 22',
      area: 'Area 2'
    }
  ];


  $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
    group: "area"
  }, {
    dataset: $scope.data
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.3.6" data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtl" ng-app="app">

    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover" show-group="false">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="50%" />
        <col width="30%" />
      </colgroup>
      <tr class="ng-table-group" ng-repeat-start="group in $groups">
        <td colspan="2">
          <a href="">
                  {{ group.value }}
                </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="u in group.data" ng-repeat-end>
        <td title="'User ID'">{{ u.uid }}</td>
        <td title="'Name'">{{ u.name }}</td>
        <td title="'Area'">{{ u.area }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/M8BcStInfSaSEaq6UVN7?p=preview[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/M8BcStInfSaSEaq6UVN7?p=preview)

Comment: So you want only one `Area` visible at one time ?

Comment: Yea, at first I need to show only one area.Other areas should be collapsed.But in the above plunker we are able to see both the areas.

Comment: But if the user click on the second area, should it collapse the first area or not ?

Comment: It should collapse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable containing the active row to achieve this. You initiate it to the default active row :

```
$scope.visibleRow = 'Area 1';
```

And you update it on an **ngClick** (the `ng-click` is inside an `ng-repeat` so you need to refere to the parent scope) :

```
ng-click="$parent.visibleRow = group.value"
```

And you make the row hidden if it doesn't correspond to the `visibleRow` :

```
ng-hide="$parent.visibleRow != u.area"
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vjb5FzmbcciFLBOtXfmH?p=preview) is a working plunker.

Comment: That's brilliant.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**[ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)** provides properties like $first (true if the repeated element is first in the iterator), $index, $middle and $last.

You can use $first to expand only the first row :)